# Clear Pivottables if Resource Data are empty

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to check if an Sheet where the Resource Data of 3 Pivot tables is empty, if yes it should clear the Pivottables Content in another Sheet without deleting the Pivottable. For now my Problem ist that the Pivottable also after an update stay filed with the last value and dont clear themself. I get all the time an Error that the Method dont match. Here is my Code:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim myCellRange As Range
Set myCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A500")

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").CountA(myCellRange) = 0 Then
    Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").PivotTables(1)
    pt.ClearTable
End If
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please checkthe below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub clearPivot()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim lastrow As Long




lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


        If lastrow = 1 Then



        Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").PivotTables(1)

            pt.ClearTable

        End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says that the Index is out of range

Comment: Erorr 400 when run over Button from Sheet, Error 1004 when Run from VBA Enviroment

Comment: Sorry that is not possible, but i checked your code part by part the Problem occures with the ClearTable function

Comment: please check the names of your sheets, I have tried the code and works perfectly, I have also post and images.

Comment: Sub clearPivot()

Dim st As PivotTable
    Set st = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").PivotTables(1)
    st.ClearTable

End Sub

Comment: I tried also this only for the one sheet but still I get the same error

Comment: the above error fired when not exist a pivot table, please make sure that you have a pivot table... I tried the code without pivot table and this error appeared

Comment: There are defenitly 3 Pivot tables in the sheet, could it be that it apears because off multiple pivot tables?

Comment: Actually I didi an error messege box, it say that it canot do that on connected Cells

Answer (score 0):

try this. To use worksheet functions in VBA code, you need to address them from `application.WorksheetFunction` object.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim myCellRange As Range
Set myCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A500")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myCellRange) = 0 Then
    Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").PivotTables(1)
    pt.ClearTable
End If
```

Comment: The same as the one up, it says the index is out of range

Comment: once you clear your pivottable, it will take more Column space, so if you had Pivottable which took only one column in width, when you clear it, it will take 3 columns of space. Make sure that you do not have any merged cells in columns next to PivotTable, or any other object which will unable PT clearing.